# Ruby on rails, jquery. Geocoder searching

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-geocoder

I have a search box and a geocoded model. I trying to use jquery to automatically search after entering an address. So far, pressing the enter key works and searches the first item in the list (google autocomplete list), but I'm struggling to search after selecting an autocomplete list item with mouse click.

```
<div class="search-form-cont">
  <%= f.search_field :date_gteq, value: Date.today, :format => :short, placeholder: t('gig.from') %>
  <%= f.search_field :date_lteq %>
  <%= f.submit class: 'gig-s-btn' %> placeholder: t('gig.until') %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'loc-search' %>
  <%= f.collection_select :genres_id_in, Genre.order(:id), :id, :name, {},:data => {}, :multiple => true %>
  <%= f.submit class: 'gig-s-btn' %>
  <input type="button" id="clearsearch" value="clear" />
```

Hitting enter works;

```
$('.loc-search').keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
    {
      $(".gig-s-btn").click()
    }
  });
```

But mouse clicks don't, nothing happens;

```
$('.pac-item').mousedown(function() {
      $(".gig-s-btn").click()
    });
```

I'm very new to query and really struggling with this. I have tried a ton of other things but none work in the desired way.

EDIT:

As .pac-item is dynamically created content, I have tried;

```
$(document).on('click', '.pac-item', function(){
      $(".gig-s-btn").submit();
    });
```

Which doesn't work either.

EDIT 2:

This submit the form on mouse click but doesn't work very well.

```
$('body').on( "mouseup", '.pac-item', function(){
      $(".gig-s-btn").closest('form').submit()
    });
```

If I were to type 'New' and 'New York' appears in the list, clicking 'New York' would submit the form but with search query 'New' only, leaving no, or undersired results.

EDIT 3:

This is working for me:

```
$('body').on( 'mousedown', '.pac-item', function(){
     setTimeout(function() {
      $(".gig-s-btn").closest('form').submit()
    }, 1);
   });
```

The mouseup event doesn't work as the container disappears on mousedown, so I used mousedown and set a delay of 1 millisecond to allow the form to populate before firing the search.

Comment: what are you using for doing the autocomplete? `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` I presume? the documentation and code samples [https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/](https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/) are pretty complete and just work

Comment: I am using the geocoder gem

Answer (score 0):

don't try to .click() the gig-s-btn element, just .submit() the form so change to

```
    $('.pac-item').mousedown(function() {
      $(".gig-s-btn").closeset('form').submit();
    });
```

I have put a quick snippet on JSFiddle (although the form errors on submit) if you click the divs that are the drop down text the form will be submitted. https://jsfiddle.net/saramic/7szkg8x7/

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply, yes I have now changed it to submit. The problem is that clicks don't seem to get registered on .pac-item or pac-container... nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, pac-item is dynamically added after page load, so I tried $(document).on('click', '.pac-item', function(){
      $(".gig-s-btn").submit();
    }); which still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, you want to submit the form, not the button. So either using the class/id on the form directly or finding the closest form from the button as mentioned `$(".gig-s-btn").closest('form').submit()`

Comment: I have it half working with:  ` $('body').on( "mouseup", '.pac-item', function(){
      $(".gig-s-btn").closest('form').submit()
    });` I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
$('body').on( 'mousedown', '.pac-item', function(){
     setTimeout(function() {
      $(".gig-s-btn").closest('form').submit()
    }, 1);
   });
```

The mouseup event doesn't work as the container disappears on mousedown, so I used mousedown and set a delay of 1 millisecond to allow the form to populate before firing the search.

I am very new to jquery so if this is too hacky and there is a better solution I would love to know.